# Acer 5755g has no battery icon after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

My laptop (and Acer 5755g) has no battery icon after installing Windows 8.
I can't be enable it using the icon manager either.

Comment: Found solution, will answer in time:

Go to device manager, right click and uninstall "microsoft compliant ac adapter"

go to action>scan for new hardware. 

It'll find the battery and you wont even need to reboot

Comment: So you basically installed the drivers for the device

Comment: Indeed, but from the device manager it looks like it's already installed properly and working.